# How to put current date in to my SQL datediff

Tags: php, mysql

This is a query which I tried below.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,due, datediff(date('Y/m/d'), date)  FROM sales
```

I am writing a sales program for identifying the due payment.
If the due payment is more than 7 error displayed payment pending what I tried so far I attached below of the full coding. when I tried the below code error ouput displayed

> Notice: Undefined index: datediff(pay_date, date)

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $today = date("Y/m/d");
    $sql = "SELECT id,due, datediff(date('Y/m/d'), date)  FROM sales where due != '0' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $paydate = $row["datediff(pay_date, date)"] . " " .  "Days" . "</br>";
            if ($paydate >= 7) {
                $status = "Payment pending";
                $color = "#47f50b";
            } elseif ($paydate >= 3) {
                $status = "Payment pending please settle down the amount";
                $color = "yellow";
            } elseif ($paydate >= 1) {
                $status = "kindly pay the payment";
                $color = "#00a8ff";
            } elseif ($paydate == 0) {
                $status = "Disable your Order";
                $color = "red";
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your due date column is called `date`, then your query should be

```
$sql = "SELECT id, due, DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE()) AS paydate FROM sales WHERE due != '0' ";
```

Note that we use [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) to get the current date in MySQL, and that I have aliased the `DATEDIFF` result to `paydate`.

You also have an issue that you are trying to set

```
$paydate =  $row ["datediff(pay_date, date)"]
```

however in your query your expression does not match `datediff(pay_date, date)`. This is why it's better to use an alias as I did above, then you can change that line to simply

```
$paydate = $row['paydate'];
```

and if you change the formula in your query this part of the code will still work.

Finally you are appending `" Days"` to the value of `$paydate`. This will make comparisons with numbers e.g. in `if($paydate >= 7)` problematic and it would be better if you left off the `" Days"` until you output the value of `$paydate`.

Comment: SELECT id, due, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) AS paydate FROM sales WHERE due != '0'        if i write like this paydate shows   -5 , -4 ,-2 like this sir . can you write full code it easy to understand

Comment: I misinterpreted your data, just swap `CURDATE()` and `date` i.e. `DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE())`

Comment: can you write the full code easy forme to understand

Comment: SELECT id, due, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),pay_ date) AS paydate FROM sales WHERE due != '0' it is still display nagitive numbers -5 -4 -2 like wise check paydate between current date

Answer (score 0):

Try using `datediff(pay_date, date) as datedif` in the SELECT and print using `$row["datedif"]`